# Decrease the height of a row in a datagrid

Tags: checkbox, datagrid, styles, height, react-admin

How can apply style to decrease a data-grid row height which has a `checkbox` in the first column in react-admin?
I'm trying to change `rowstyle` property for data-grid, but by default `checkbox` is showed and not for apart component.

Thanks.

[App screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeOBH.png)

Comment: in react-admin marmelab

Answer (score 0):

Showing checkbox can be turned off: `<List bulkActionButtons={false} ... >`

```
import { withStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const styles = theme => createStyles({
  row: { 
    height: '35px',
  }
})

const MyList = withStyles(styles)(({ classes, ...props }) => (
  <List bulkActionButtons={false} {...props} >
    <Datagrid classes={classes} >
    ...
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need the checkbox be visible.